# Improving fit by adding weights

Tags: fitting

I have the data:

```
data0 = {{0, 0.047}, {40, 0.071}, {80, 0.103}, {120, 0.169}, {160, 0.292}, {200, 0.498}, {240, 0.777}, {280, 1.000}, {320, 1.227}};
```

I want to fit a logistic function to it, so:

```
F = NonlinearModelFit[data0, A/(1 + E^(-(t - t0)/b)), {{A, 1.2}, {t0, 200}, {b, 60}}, t];
F["ParameterTable"]
```

The fit doesn't look like bad:
[image]

Now, we are given the corresponding standard deviations as: $0.003, 0.008, 0.010, 0.012, 0.023, 0.024, 0.061, 0.135, 0.221$. If we use these as weights, one can write:

```
F = NonlinearModelFit[data0, A/(1 + E^(-(t - t0)/b)), {{A, 1.2}, {t0, 200}, {b, 60}}, t, Weights -> 1/{0.003, 0.008, 0.010, 0.012, 0.023, 0.024, 0.061, 0.135, 0.221}];
F["ParameterTable"]
```

But now the fit becomes much worse:
[image]

What is the most effective way to use standard deviation in order to obtain more informative and better fit?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that including weights will result in a "better looking" fit?  If the weights are correct, then you'll (tend) to get better estimates of the parameters and more appropriate estimates of the associated standard errors.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your comment. Doesn't better estimates of the parameters lead to better fit?

Comment: It does (generally) result in a better fit. But you are stating that it is a worse fit by the way it looks to you. That is what is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One needs to have a model (a predictive part and an error structure) to know what to do with the weights.  If the weights are appropriate for the model, then one will tend to get better estimates of the parameters in the sense that the precision of the estimates will improve from not using weights.  But one cannot judge the improvement just by looking at the overall change in fit from not using weights to using weights.

Consider the following model:

$$y_i={a \over{1+e^{-(t_i-t_0)/b}}}+w_i \epsilon_i$$

where $y_i$ is the $i$-th response, $t_i$ is the $i$-th predictor, $a$, $b$, and $t_0$ are constants to be estimated, the errors ($\epsilon_i$) are all independent, and $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ for the $n$ observations with $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

The *Mathematica* code for fitting such a model is as follows:

```
(* Data and weights *)
data = {{0, 0.047}, {40, 0.071}, {80, 0.103}, {120, 0.169}, {160, 0.292}, 
  {200, 0.498}, {240, 0.777}, {280, 1.000}, {320, 1.227}};
w = {0.003, 0.008, 0.010, 0.012, 0.023, 0.024, 0.061, 0.135, 0.221};

(* Fit *)
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a/(1 + E^(-(t - t0)/b)), {{a, 1.2}, {t0, 200}, {b, 60}}, t, 
  Weights -> 1/w^2]
mle = nlm["BestFitParameters"]
σ = nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5
```

To check on whether using weights tends to result in better estimates for the parameters one can perform simulations.  Suppose we use the estimated coefficients from your data as the "true" model.  (But I'm reducing the size of the error variance to a tenth of the above estimate to avoid lack-of-convergence issues which can be especially problematic when the weights are ignored.)

```
(* Number of data points *)
n = Length[data];
(* Predictors *)
x = data[[All, 1]];
(* Scale down the variance to avoid lack-of-convergence issues *)
σ = 0.1 nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5
(* Number of simulations *)
nsim = 200;

(* Generate mean prediction and errors *)
meanPrediction = a/(1 + Exp[-(x - t0)/b]);
errors = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σ], {nsim, n}];

(* Generate nsim datasets *)
datasim = meanPrediction + meanPrediction w # & /@ errors /. mle;
datasim = Transpose[{x, #}] & /@ datasim;

(* Now perform fits with and without weights *)
initialValues = {{a, (a /. mle)}, {b, (b /. mle)}, {t0, (t0 /. mle)}};
withWeights = {a, b, t0} /. NonlinearModelFit[#, a/(1 + Exp[-(t - t0)/b]),
  initialValues, t, Weights -> 1/w^2, MaxIterations -> 5000]["BestFitParameters"] & /@ datasim;
withoutWeights = {a, b, t0} /. NonlinearModelFit[#, a/(1 + Exp[-(t - t0)/b]),
  initialValues, t, MaxIterations -> 10000]["BestFitParameters"] & /@ datasim;
```

Now plot a smooth histogram of the estimates of each of the parameters with and without using weights:

```
Show[SmoothHistogram[{withoutWeights[[All, 1]], withWeights[[All, 1]]},
  Automatic, "PDF", PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, 2}},
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"a", "Density"},
  PlotLegends -> {"Without weights", "With weights"}],
 ListPlot[{{a /. mle, 0}}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.02]}}],
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]

Show[SmoothHistogram[{withoutWeights[[All, 2]], withWeights[[All, 2]]},
  Automatic, "PDF", Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"b", "Density"},
  PlotLegends -> {"Without weights", "With weights"}],
 ListPlot[{{b /. mle, 0}}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.02]}}],
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]

Show[SmoothHistogram[{withoutWeights[[All, 3]], withWeights[[All, 3]]},
  Automatic, "PDF", PlotRange -> {{250, 500}, {0, .08}},
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"t0", "Density"},
  PlotLegends -> {"Without weights", "With weights"}],
 ListPlot[{{t0 /. mle, 0}}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.02]}}],
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image: Smooth histograms of parameter estimates with and without weights]

The red dots are the true values.  One can see a great improvement by using weights (at least in this case where we know how the data was generated as used an estimation approach that matched the model).  Much "tighter" estimates using weights.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answered! Please give me time to understand it. Just a first question: do you mean $t_i$ in the line under "Consider the following model", where you have written instead $x_i$?

Comment: Another question: In your model, $\epsilon_i$, is the error and $w_i$ is a coefficient. But this $w_i$ is not the $w$ in your code, which is the standard deviation. Am I correct? Because I found notation confusing.

Comment: And also, where is this $w_i$ used in your code?

Comment: This list of $w_i$ values is defined in code (as `w`) right after `data` is defined and used with `NonlinearModelFit` function for both the original data and the simulated data with `Weights -> 1/w^2`.  Also the $w_i$ are known coefficients that you supplied.

Comment: Sometimes when the weights are the known standard deviations, then one can write $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,1)$ rather than $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, your result demonstrates that although "visually" the fit becomes worse when we add weights, but in fact, the estimation of parameters become better when we add weights?

Comment: Not exactly.  To be blunt:  the fit is only "visually" worse to someone who doesn't understand the effect of weights.  Note that the "worsening" of the visual fit is generally at the points where the standard deviation is higher.  And the fit is "visually better" for the points with more weight  (i.e., smaller standard deviations).

Comment: Sorry, I missed your initial comment.  Yes, that is my mistake about using $x_i$ instead of $t_i$.  I'll fix that.  Thanks.

Comment: Just a final question: As my data points are mean values, do you think it's better to define $w$ in your code as the given standard deviations in the question as you have already done or to define $w$ as the standard error which can be obtained by dividing the standard deviations by the square root of sample size?

Comment: The weights should be proportional to the standard deviation of the observation (whether that is a single observation or the mean of several observations).  If all of the sample points have the same number of observations used to calculate the mean, then it doesn't matter.  (Note that all standard errors are standard deviations for some summary statistic.)  While the estimates and estimated precision of the parameters will be fine, if the objective is to find the precision of a single prediction at some value of $t$, then explicit accounting for the means is necessary.  That would be a new q.

Comment: A communication with you was like attending a course on statistics! Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  (Although I'm not sure how to interpret that.  Either it's a compliment or a sarcastic comment which being sarcastic myself, I do appreciate.)